# How to render a custom component after sigin with AWS Amplify in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I want render my app after sigin in using Amplify react ui components.
Here is what my code looks like.

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Logo />
        <Authenticator usernameAttributes="email">
            <Home />
        </Authenticator>
    </View>
```

Here is the Home component.

```
const Home = (props) => {
if (props.authState === 'signedIn') {
    return <Text>Home</Text>;
} else {
    return <></>;
}};
```

[Here is how it looks after signin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFfP2.png)

Comment: You can use WithAuthenticator HOC for better authstate handling and rendering correct component

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass something to the Home component.

Something like this:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Logo />
    <Authenticator usernameAttributes="email">
        <Home authState={authState}/>
    </Authenticator>
</View>
```

Where authState receives a variable that specifies whether the user is signed in or not as a string for you to be able to compare it using props.authState === 'signedIn'